# Using django-bootstrap-toolkit with a django-registration field to remove labels

Tags: python, django, django-registration

I'm fairly new to both `django` and `django-bootstrap-toolkit`

I am trying to style a login form I have functioning with django-registration and haven't been able to figure out how to full stylize the username `{{form.username}}` and password `{{form.password}}` fields with `django-bootstrap-toolkit`.

I would like to remove the labels of those fields and also add "placeholder text" inside them.

I tried `{{ form.username|as_bootstrap }}` and it provided some styling but I can't figure out how to remove the label and add placeholder text to those fields.

Most examples I have found involve working through the form.py but I'm not sure how to get to that module for django-registration (again I am pretty new at this)

I appreciate the time and expertise.

Answer (score 0):

you can make your own form in forms.py, like this:

```
from registration.forms import RegistrationForm

class FormLogin(RegistrationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(label='',
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={'placeholder':'Username'}
        )
     )

    password = forms.CharField(label='',
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(
        attrs={'placeholder':'Password'}
        )
    )
```

then in your urls.py:

```
from registration.views import register
import registration.backends.default.urls as regUrls
from forms import FormLogin

url(r'^accounts/register/$', register, {'form_class': FormLogin}, 
name='registration_register')    
(r'^accounts/', include(regUrls)),
```

Comment: How can I get my own form in this example to work with django-registration? As I'm learning it seems like I need to work with django-regristrations fields if I want to use that app.

Comment: @user2016740 now I'm using the forms from django-registration. You can also see more info here: http://dmitko.ru/django-registration-form-custom-field/

Comment: I really appreciate the response. I've added the code as shown above but now I get the following error when trying to load the login page: NameError at /
name 'FormLogin' is not defined  Do I need to import 'FormLogin' somewhere? Thanks again for the help.

Comment: I think I'm getting close. How do I display the new fields in my template? I tried {{FormLogin.username}} with no luck. I'm a little confused because I've learned to display fields from forms.py through the view and in this case I don't access django-registation's view.

Comment: in this case I think you can use `{{ form_class.username }}`

Comment: {{ form_class.username }} didn't display the field. I'm not getting any errors. Any thoughts on what else I can try?

Comment: I'm sorry, you have to use `{{form.username}}`. You can also do something like that: `{% for field in form %}
  <tr>
   <td><p class="hint {%if field.field.required %} bold {% endif %}"{{ field.label_tag }}</p>
   {{ field }}</td>
    
   {% if field.help_text %}<td class="clearfix">{{ field.help_text }}</td>{% endif %}
   {% if field.errors %}<td class="myerrors clearfix">{{ field.errors }}</td>{% endif %}
  
  </tr>
 {% endfor %}
`

Comment: The fields will display with {{form.username}}. If I leave the "|as_boostrap" off then the labels won't show but they do who if it is present. One key thing is the attrs={'placeholder':'Username'} is not working as there is no placeholder in the field. I really appreciate your time. Any thoughts?

Comment: what if you do this? {{ form|as_bootstrap }}

Comment: {{ form|as_bootstrap }} displays the form but the label are present and the placeholders are not displayed.